# bubble sort by only single loop

Tags: java, sorting

I am doing sorting of numbers by bubble sort. where as I want to see if this sorting can be done by using only single loop, as we use 2 for loops in bubble sort. Can someone please tell me how it can be done and also if it is even possible ?

Comment: of course you can linearize two nested 1-variable loops into one 2-variable loop, but it will be harder to read and understand, and complexity won't change. What is your exact problem?

Comment: @sasha, I want to sort the array with only one loop. not more than that. I am using Java. I am still finding any solution which suits my query. all given answers are not working properly.

Comment: @vidit, that link also not useful.

Comment: I gave an approach. Duplicate question contains an algorithm. What else do you wait? For someone who will write a fully tested code for you? Despite your problem is simple, it is not enough *interesting* for us to waste time on it.

Answer (score 3):

Bubble sort works by moving pairs of values which are next to each other. So, for example, you have this list:

`list = {5, 3, 6, 11, 2}`

The first iteration, will go, pair by pair, switching positions if its necessary:

1. Compare 5 and 3. 3 is smaller, so you switch => `{3, 5, 6, 11, 2}`
2. Compare 5 and 6. 5 is smaller, so you do nothing => `{3, 5, 6, 11, 2}`
3. Compare 6 and 11. 6 is smaller, so you do nothing => `{3, 5, 6, 11, 2}`
4. Compare 11 and 2. 2 is smaller, so you witch => `{3, 5, 6, 2, 11}`

We have completed 1 iteration of the loop, and as you see, the list is not sorted. You need to iterate multiple times in order to achieve the sorting.

What can be done, though, is to use only 1 loop that keeps iterating until it is sorted, which would be achieved by altering the iteration index based on the original bubble sort switch flag:

```
bool valuesSwitched = false;
int list[5] = {5, 3, 6, 11, 2};
int len = 5;
for(int i = 1; i <= len; i++)
{
    if(i == len)
    {
        if(!valuesSwitched) break;

        valuesSwitched = false;
        i = 1;
    }
    if(list[i - 1] > list[i])
    {
        int temp = list[i - 1];
        list[i - 1] = list[i];
        list[i] = temp;
        valuesSwitched = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: it didn't work by your solution not giving the correct output.

Comment: I didnt have time to test it, but I posted it as an example of how to do it with one loop. The key concept is not to exit the loop until no changes have been made to it. What output it gives?